# Getting ClassicEditor exported on custom build of CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, build, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to build CKEditor 5 using "Scenario 2" as described here:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html

And it is almost working. in my `app.js` which get compiled together with the editor by webpack I can reference `ClassicEditor.create` and thus create a new editor :)

But `ClassicEditor` don't get exported, so any external javascript which is not compiled by Webpack can't reference `ClassicEditor` (I just get "ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined").

So how do I get `ClassicEditor` exported?

Here are the files I use:

```
app.js:
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import UploadadapterPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';
import AutoformatPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import BlockquotePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import EasyimagePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image/src/easyimage';
import HeadingPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import ImagePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImagecaptionPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption';
import ImagestylePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle';
import ImagetoolbarPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar';
import ImageuploadPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload';
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import ListPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';

export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

ClassicEditor.build = {
    plugins: [
        EssentialsPlugin,
        UploadadapterPlugin,
        AutoformatPlugin,
        BoldPlugin,
        ItalicPlugin,
        BlockquotePlugin,
        EasyimagePlugin,
        HeadingPlugin,
        ImagePlugin,
        ImagecaptionPlugin,
        ImagestylePlugin,
        ImagetoolbarPlugin,
        ImageuploadPlugin,
        LinkPlugin,
        ListPlugin,
        ParagraphPlugin
    ],
    config: {
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'heading',
                '|',
                'bold',
                'italic',
                'link',
                'bulletedList',
                'numberedList',
                'imageUpload',
                'blockQuote',
                'undo',
                'redo'
            ]
        },
        image: {
            toolbar: [
                'imageStyle:full',
                'imageStyle:side',
                '|',
                'imageTextAlternative'
            ]
        },
        language: 'en'
    }
};
```

webpack.config.js:

```
// webpack.config.js

'use strict';

const path = require( 'path' );
const { styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );

module.exports = {
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    entry: './app.js',

    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Or /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/ if you want to limit this loader
                // to CKEditor 5 icons only.
                test: /\.svg$/,

                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
                // Or /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/[^/]+\.css$/ if you want to limit this loader
                // to CKEditor 5 theme only.
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            singleton: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                            },
                            minify: true
                        } )
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    // Useful for debugging.
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I just need to add

```
window.ClassicEditor=ClassicEditor;
```

at the bottom of my app.js file

Comment: You saved my life ! I'm not an expert in JS, so just a question: why does it do the trick...! 
Thanks