# API not available after custom build

Tags: ckeditor5

I successfully built the ClassicEditor from source with the inline widget plugin (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html). If I include

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
...
```

in `app.js`, I am able to create an instance of the editor, with the plugin available. However, when I include `ckeditor.js` in my page, and try to run the same code to initialize an editor, I get

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ClassicEditor
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works here:

[Getting ClassicEditor exported on custom build of CKEditor 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657924/getting-classiceditor-exported-on-custom-build-of-ckeditor-5)

Basically add `window.ClassicEditor=ClassicEditor;` to the bottom of `app.js`.

That doesn't make all the plugins available to reference when creating a ClassicEditor instance, but I can just specify those as default plugins in `app.js`. Not really sure if this is the way it's supposed to be done, since the samples from the online builder don't work this way, but there are no clear directions so this will work for my purposes.

Comment: getting same result.. coul dyou point me to how to add the plugins as default?